# How to sum 2 text boxes into a 3 text box on form

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get the value in `textboxA` (text) + value in `textboxB` (text) to populate in `textboxC` (number).

In control source expression builder for `textboxC` I have:

```
=[TextboxA]+[TextboxB]
```

I have also tried:

```
=Nz([TextboxA],0)+Nz(TextboxB],0)
```

I found the above on this site but it is not working because if I enter `1` in `textboxA` and `2` in `textboxB` then `textboxC` shows `12`.

I am using Access 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the format of your textboxes to **General Number** or convert the text content to a number using the [`Val`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/val-function-e5e1f21b-22f9-41c9-bd0a-fe55b767f603) function, e.g.:

```
=Val(Nz([TextboxA]))+Val(Nz([TextboxB]))
```

Comment: Although you want to be careful using `Val`, since it might return unexpected results. `Val` parses the string until a non-numeric value is found. So `Val("    1615 198th Street N.E.")` returns `1615198`. You might want to instead use one of the explicit conversion functions (e.g. `CInt` or `CLng`), and catch type conversion errors.

Comment: I changed some of text boxes to text because on the form in was putting a zero in the box and I was not able to change the number.

Comment: I tried this =Val([textboxA])+Val(textboxB]) and now in the textbox C it has #Type!

Comment: this one worked: =Val(Nz([TextboxA]))+Val(Nz([TextboxB]))

Comment: however it is not placing the amount in textbox c in the table?

Comment: @Deb What made you think it would update a table? If the Control Source is set to the expression provided, the control is not bound to a single field in the Record Source of the form. To populate a field with the result of the calculation you will likely need to use the `After Update` event of each textbox.

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve it. If my answer sufficiently answered your original question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this.